# How do I redirect to the current page using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

On clicking a link, it should redirect to the current page.  How do I do this with JavaScript?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Assuming you mean the link should refresh the current page, you can use `window.location.reload()`. In jQuery it would look like this:

```html
<a href="#" id="myLink">Refresh current page</a>
```

```js
$("#myLink").click(function() {
    window.location.reload();
});
```

In plain JS it would look like this:

```js
document.querySelector("#myLink").addEventListener('click', function() {
    window.location.reload();
});
```

Comment: Assuming he/she uses jQuery.

Comment: @DannyThunder It's tagged in the question

Comment: Aa didnt notice that small tag :-)

Comment: For future reference, if this answer was enough to the Post Owner, I believe it does not answer the question itself. If the user has just performed a Post, he will perform the Post again and this is not what the question stands for. Redirecting to the same url is the same as redirecting to any url. Depending on the desired behaviour (redirect or navigate).

Answer (score 12):

Redirecting to the current URL is the same as redirecting to any url:

```
// Same as clicking on a link
window.location.href = window.location.href;

// Same as HTTP redirecting
window.location.replace(window.location.href);
```

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, what does 'HTTP redirecting' mean, if we aren't talking about server side redirect (like mod-rewrite in Apache)?  Surely, any attempt by javascript in the browser to change the browser's current address is a simply navigation?  is there a physically detectable side effect of one that's different to the other, or is this a logical distinction? Is this any better than the `window.location.reload()` solution from 7 years ago, from Rory McCrossan above (edit: slightly beaten to the punch by Frédéric Hamidi  in a comment on the original question)?

Comment: I think the first option listed here is the correct answer.  `location.reload` doesn't seem to reload the page as if it was first loaded, where `location.href = location.href` does.

Answer (score 4):

Example using a button:

```
<input type="button" value="Reload Page" onClick="window.location.reload()">
```

See here:

http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/page/reload.html

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way to do it using vanilla JS without inlining it and without jQuery:

```
<a href="#" id="myLink">Refresh current page</a>  

<script>
    document.querySelector("a#myLink").onclick = function(){
        window.location.reload();
    }; 
</script>
```

note the [list of supported browsers](http://caniuse.com/queryselector) when considering using querySelector()