# Unable to redirect to html page after inserting form data into database

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#sub").click( function() {                                 
    $.post($("#new_user").attr("action"), $("#new_user :input").serializeArray(), function(info) { 
        $("#result").html(info);  
    });  
    clearInput();  
});  

$("#new_user").submit(function() {  
    return false;  
}); 

function clearInput() {  
    $("#new_user :input").each(function() {  
        $(this).val('');  
    });  
}
```

Here `sub` is the id of the HTML form and `result` is the id of a span tag in the same page as the form. I am looking to redirect to the same HTML page after inserting in the database, which is not happening. Insertion is happening properly.

Comment: I think this link will help full to you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376596/how-do-i-redirect-to-the-current-page-using-javascript

Comment: What's the point of using AJAX if you want to redirect immediately after it finishes anyway?

Comment: forget AJAX - simply pass the form to a regular php page that processes the inputs, updates the database adn redirects to the page after completion - the whole point of AJAX is to allow form submission WITHOUT page reload and if you actually want to reload - then its not AJAX you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

use this method to redorect

```
window.location = "http://www.youtube.com";
```

or use this in your function where you want to redirect

```
$(this).attr("href","http://www.youtube.com");
```

give your own url